# Is it possible to prioritise the product order in Adobe Business Catalyst?

Tags: content-management-system, business-catalyst

A client has asked if they can prioritise a certain product in their online catalogue so that it appears as the second product rather than the sixth or so. Is this possible?

This is all I can find in the help section, which points to a **no** answer.

> **Customizing how sub-catalogs list appears**
>   `{tag_cataloguelist,rowLength,targetFrame,notUsed,sortType,hideEmptyMessage,list/table}`
>
> **rowLength** Number of catalogs per
>   row
>   **targetFrame** e.g. _blank.
>   Specify the frame you want the product
>   to open in
>   **resultsPerPage**
>   Number of catalogs you wish to display
>   before the page paginates
>  
>   **notUsed** this field is not currently
>   used. Leave empty.
>   **sortType**
>               - Alphabetical
>               - Weight (Defaut)
>   **hideEmptyMessage** if a catalog does not
>   have any sub-catalogs you will see a
>   message
>   This catalog has no
>   sub-catalogs. You can hide it by
>   setting it to true.

Hopefully I'm just missing a really obvious control in the BC interface somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So that help documentation you've pulled up is regarding catalogs. If you want the catalogs to appear in a different order, use the "Weight" sortType in your tag_cataloguelist and assign weights to your catalogs when setting them up.

For individual products in the list view, assign a weight to each product under eCommerce > Products in the detailed product settings. You can also assign weights in bulk by downloading the entire product list then reimporting the product database.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I misinterpreted that as being the product's physical weight all along.. Whoops.